# Depurar aplicações em NodeJS

Tags: node.js, debug

Quais a melhores ferramentas para serem utilizadas na depuração de aplicações node na opinião de vocês?

Comment: Apesar de ter respondido, estou dando um voto negativo à pergunta por ser uma informação facilmente encontrada na documentação do node. Se você tiver uma pergunta mais específica sobre o uso do debugger do node, por favor edite a pergunta.

Comment: Eu acho a pergunta muito pertinente, pois depurar no console muitas vezes quebra o galho, mas ter uma ferramenta profissional para isso é essencial quando se desenvolve aplicações robustas.

Comment: @DanielT.Sobrosa O problema dessa pergunta é ser abrangente demais. Talvez uma pergunta melhor seria: "Como usar o node debugger para depurar aplicações Node no console?" e as outras versões equivalentes. Note que a sua resposta ficou grande e ainda precisa pular detalhes -- por exemplo, você precisou assumir que o OP sabe depurar uma aplicação utilizando um depurador.

Comment: Apesar da pergunta ter sido muito bem respondida, gostaria apenas de acrecentar: Eu gosto muito de usar o https://codenvy.com/ para desenvolver em node. A IDE é na nuvem e já possui tudo que preciso para trabalhar. No meu caso atende bem pois não desenvolvo profissionalmente em Node.

Comment: É verdade. Mas eu tive o mesmo problema quando comecei no node, não sabia que ferramenta a comunidade estava usando. E continuo sem saber, mas eu achei uma que caiu como uma luva no meu modo de trabalhar. Por isso achei válida a pergunta.

Comment: Agradeço as respostas e concordo que eu poderia ter sido mais específico, porem ao realizar pesquisas rápidas não tinha encontrado nada que me parecesse "o mais usado". A pergunta foi mais para saber opiniões.

Comment: Acho a questão pertinente. Horas, se o mesmo autor **realizou uma pesquisa sobre** e não encontrou uma resposta satisfatória, por que não perguntar aqui? Mais pessoas que estejam iniciando no NodeJS podem chegar até esse site através da pergunta dele.

Comment: Considero a pergunta válida, entretanto não acho interessante usar expressões como "na opinião de vocês" já que isso tira a objetividade da resposta. Mesmo assim, acho que deve ser reaberta.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

O próprio node já possui uma ferramenta de debug, basta executar o seu módulo node da seguinte maneira:

```
node debug nome_do_seu_modulo
```

Segue a documentação para ver como funciona:
http://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html

Porém existe o `node-inspector` que permite utilizar o browser para depurar. Basta startar o debugger e acessar a url no browser. Segue documentação:
https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector

---

**Usando o Node Inspector**

Instale via npm:

```
$ npm install -g node-inspector
```

Inicie o debugger:

```
node-inspector
```

Inicie seu app em modo debug:

```
$ node --debug your/short/node/script.js
```

Ou inicie dizendo para pausar na primeira linha:

```
$ node --debug-brk your/short/node/script.js
```

Acesse a url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?port=5858
```

Pronto, é só depurar no browser!

---

**Usando o debugger do node**

Inicie seu app em modo debug:

```
node debug meu_app
```

Nesse momento o debugger vai parar na primeira linha, daí em diante é só depurar. Segue alguns comandos:

```
cont, c - Continue execution
next, n - Step next
step, s - Step in
out, o - Step out
pause - Pause running code (like pause button in Developer Tools)
```

É possível também monitorar o valor de variáveis:

```
watch( "nome_da_variavel")
```

Desta forma, a cada passo que for dado, ele vai imprimir no console o valor das variáveis observadas.

É possível também escrever expressões, basta usar o comando `repl` e digitar as expressões. Para voltar digite Ctrl + C.

Consulte a [documentação](http://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html#debugger_commands_reference) para ter mais detalhes sobre os comandos.

Comment: É realmente simples de fazer e dá um ganho imenso na produtividade ao depurar uma aplicação node.

Answer (score 5):

Além do próprio [debugger do node](http://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html) recentemente lançaram o [Node.js Tools for Visual Studio](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools#readme).

o add-on parece promissor e, na minha opnião, o Visual Studio é uma das melhores IDE para *debugar* que existem... recomendo dar uma olhada.

Answer (score 3):

O Node tem um [debugger](http://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html), que você roda assim:

```
node debug myscript.js
```

Answer (score 3):

Eu uso as IDE's da JetBrains para Java, Ruby e Node.js (utilizo o plugin do Node no RubyMine). Então costumo utilizar o debugger na própria IDE. http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/running-and-debugging-node-js.html